# call :ProcessArgs /? produces call help rather than calling :ProcessArgs with "/?"

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that processes some command line options and I'd like it to also handle /? and -?.  The later works fine, but when I use /? I get the call help spew and never call the subroutine. I did some searching here SO, but couldn't find anything specific to this problem in the all those many results.

Here's the simplest I could strip it down to:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@set prompt=$G

call :ProcessArgs %*

@exit /b 0

:ProcessArgs
@echo %*
@exit /b 0
```

When called with -? everything is fine, but /? results in:

```
>call :ProcessArgs /?
Calls one batch program from another.

CALL [drive:][path]filename [batch-parameters]

batch-parameters   Specifies any command-line information required by the
                 batch program.
...
```

That just seems like a bug to me, but I doubt I'd be discovering any new bugs in cmd.exe on my Win10 box. Using quotes around %* avoids the help spew, but also result in :ProcessArgs receiving a single argument, which I definitely don't want to happen.

Any clues or work-arounds would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: CMD is filled with bugs and surprises; in fact, I do think you have found a new _feature_ (MS' jargon for "bug").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug but it can be used as a feature ([Anonymous functions](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3803&start=15#p42446)).

In your case you can avoid that behavior by using double percents.

```
Set "args=%*"
call :ProcessArgs %%args%%"
```

Comment: that seems to be the answer I never would have thought of.  Thank you!  Unless a better answer comes along later, I'll mark this one.

Answer (score 2):

I've made two tiny changes to your sample script, and it is working for `/?` under Windows 7:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@set prompt=$G

call :ProcessArgs %%*

@exit /b 0

:ProcessArgs
@echo(%*
@exit /b 0
```

Jeb's point about escaping with double percentages appears to hold true for the wildcard argument modifier `%*`. And a small change to `@echo` is required to prevent `echo` from spewing its `help`.

Comment: Very nice. Better to use `echo(` instead of `echo[`, as there are some obscure situations where `echo[` can fail.